# Dart Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, flutter-dependencies

Error :

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel dev.fluttercommunity.plus/package_info)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:175:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:377:43)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelPackageInfo.getAll (package:package_info_plus_platform_interface/method_channel_package_info.dart:13:17)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      PackageInfo.fromPlatform (package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart:36:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I don't know where this error come from

Comment: Did you add package_info_plus but didn't completely restart your app? Also, on which platform are you having this issue, and show us part of the code that is responsible for this issue

Comment: _asyncWork() async {
    packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
  }

Answer (score 0):

Face the same issue while using
package_info_plus: ^3.0.2

Issue solved after completely restart the app/service